# Breadth First Search on Labyrinth in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, breadth-first-search

I'm trying on implementing an breadth first algorithm, that solves a labyrinth. As an input I have a n*m binary matrix, where '1' stands for obstacle/wall and '0' for path/ free cell.

I do get how the algorithm generally works, but I'm struggling with how to store and proceed the information in matlab.
So basically I start with my start cell, and check all it's direct neighbours for obstacles. If they are free, I mark them as a potential path, and then I do the same recursively for all those cells again.

But i just can't figure out how to store the information, so that in the end i will only have one path.
any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the link I referenced.  It basically has a MATLAB implementation of BFS, as well as well as GIF animation of how BFS works to get out of a maze.  However, if you want BFS to work, you need to know the starting and ending point of the maze.

Comment: However, if you want me to write an answer specifically for your case, we can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use open and closed list like in the a star pathfinding algorithm. Check the all neighbours and if the neighbour is not a obstacle, put in the open list. Examine all neighbours and the neighbour which has a min cost, put it in the closed list. In the end, you have the optimal path in the closed list. Basically it is something like that..

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that search a connected component in an unoriented graph by deep first search. BFS should be even easier to code.

```
function comp = findNodeComponentDFS(G, node)
%Find a connected component of the given node in the unoriented graph. Use
%Deep first search (Cormen, Rivest, Leiserson)
%G - connectivity matrix
%node - given node
%comp - contain the numbers of all nodes in the found connected component
%except the node itself
N = length(G);
white = ones(1,N);%unexamined vertices
grey = zeros(1,N);%vertices that are currently examining but with not all edges have been    examined yet
black = zeros(1,N);%vertices with all the edges have been examined
prev = zeros(1,N);
current = node;
stop=false;
while (~stop)
    grey(current) = 1;
    white(current) = 0;
    next = find(G(current,:) & white,1);
    if (isempty(next))
        black(current) = 1;
        if (prev(current)==0)
            stop = true;
        else
            current = prev(current);%back to previous vertice
        end
    else
        prev(next) = current;
        current = next;
    end
end
comp = find(black);
```

Comment: thanks a lot to everyone!! i got it now finally. i was just confused on how to store and reference the path, but turns out storing it in a matrix/ open list was far easier than i thought :)